# VHDL RS-232 Receiver

Tags: serial-port, vhdl, fsm

I have been trying to design an RS-232 receiver taking an FSM approach. I will admit that I do not have a very well-rounded understanding of VHDL, so I have been working on the code on the fly and learning as I go. However, I believe I've hit a brick wall at this point.

My issue is that I have two processes in my code, one to trigger the next state and the other to perform the combinational logic. My code is as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity ASyncReceiverV4 is
Port ( DataIn : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Enable : in STD_LOGIC;
           CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
              BadData : out STD_LOGIC;
           DataOut : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end ASyncReceiverV4;

architecture Behavioral of ASyncReceiverV4 is

type states is (StartBitCheck, ReadData, StopBitCheck);
signal currentState, nextState : states;

begin

    process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            currentState <= nextState;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(CLK)
    variable counter : integer := 0;
    variable dataIndex : integer := 0;
    begin
            case currentState is

                when StartBitCheck =>
                    if Enable = '1' then
                        if (DataIn = '0' and counter < 8)  then
                            counter := counter + 1;
                        elsif (DataIn = '0' and counter = 8) then
                            BadData <= '0';
                            nextState <= ReadData;
                            counter := 0;
                        else 
                            nextState <= StartBitCheck;
                        end if;
                    end if;

                when ReadData =>
                    if Enable = '1' then
                        if counter < 16 then
                            counter := counter + 1;
                        elsif (counter = 16 and dataIndex < 8) then
                            DataOut(dataIndex) <= DataIn;
                            counter := 0;
                            dataIndex := dataIndex + 1;
                        elsif dataIndex = 8 then
                            dataIndex := 0;
                            nextState <= StopBitCheck;
                        else
                            nextState <= ReadData;
                        end if;
                    end if;

                when StopBitCheck =>
                    if Enable = '1' then
                        if DataIn = '1' then
                            if counter < 16  then
                                counter := counter + 1;
                                nextState <= StopBitCheck;                          
                            elsif counter = 16 then
                                counter := 0;
                                nextState <= StartBitCheck;                         
                            end if;
                        else
                            DataOut <= "11111111";
                            BadData <= '1';
                            nextState <= StartBitCheck;
                        end if;
                    end if;

            end case;

    end process;


end Behavioral;
```

For whatever reason, based on my simulations, it seems that my processes are out of sync. Although things are only supposed to occur at the rising edge of the clock, I have transitions occurring at the falling edge. Furthermore, it seems like things are not changing according to the value of counter.

The Enable input is high in all of my simulations. However, this is just to keep it simple for now, it will eventually be fed the output of a 153,600 Baud generator (the Baud generator will be connected to the Enable input). Hence, I only want things to change when my Baud generator is high. Otherwise, do nothing. Am I taking the right approach for that with my code?

I can supply a screenshot of my simulation if that would be helpful. I am also not sure if I am including the correct variables in my process sensitivity list. Also, am I taking the right approach with my counter and dataIndex variables? What if I made them signals as part of my architecture before any of my processes?

Any help on this would be very much so appreciated!

Comment: Someone has to look at your code to be sure you're writing about a UART. Perhaps you'd consider asking at EE Stack Exchange? This is s design problem not a programming problem.

Comment: I will do that, thank you! I saw other posts regarding UARTs on here and thought I was in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this, while also producing the easiest to read code, would be to move to a 1-process state machine like so (warning: not complied may contain syntax errors):

```
entity ASyncReceiverV4 is
Port ( DataIn  : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Enable  : in  STD_LOGIC;
       CLK     : in  STD_LOGIC;
       BadData : out STD_LOGIC;
       DataOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end ASyncReceiverV4;

architecture Behavioral of ASyncReceiverV4 is
    type states is (StartBitCheck, ReadData, StopBitCheck);
    signal state     : states  := StartBitCheck;
    signal counter   : integer := 0;
    signal dataIndex : integer := 0;
begin
    process(CLK)
    begin
        if rising_edge(CLK) then
            case state is
                when StartBitCheck =>
                    if Enable = '1' then
                        if (DataIn = '0' and counter < 8)  then
                            counter <= counter + 1;
                        elsif (DataIn = '0' and counter = 8) then
                            BadData <= '0';
                            state <= ReadData;
                            counter <= 0;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                when ReadData =>
                    if Enable = '1' then
                        if counter < 16 then
                            counter <= counter + 1;
                        elsif (counter = 16 and dataIndex < 8) then
                            DataOut(dataIndex) <= DataIn;
                            counter <= 0;
                            dataIndex <= dataIndex + 1;
                        elsif dataIndex = 8 then
                            dataIndex <= 0;
                            state <= StopBitCheck;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                when StopBitCheck =>
                    if Enable = '1' then
                        if DataIn = '1' then
                            if counter < 16  then
                                counter <= counter + 1;                        
                            elsif counter = 16 then
                                counter <= 0;
                                state <= StartBitCheck;                         
                            end if;
                        else
                            DataOut <= "11111111";
                            BadData <= '1';
                            state <= StartBitCheck;
                        end if;
                    end if;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Note that while this no longer contains language issues, there are still odd things in the logic.

You cannot enter the state `StopBitCheck` until `counter` is 16 because the state transition is in an elsif of `counter < 16`. Therefore, the `if counter < 16` in `StopBitCheck` is unreachable.

Also note that the state transition to `StopBitCheck` happens on the same cycle that you would normally sample data, so the sampling of `DataIn` within `StopBitCheck` will be a cycle late. Worse, were you ever to get bad data (`DataIn/='1'` in `StopBitCheck`), `counter` would still be at 16, `StartBitCheck` would always go to the else clause, and the state machine would lock up.

---

Some more explanation on what was wrong before:

Your simulation has things changing on the negative clock edge because your combinatorial process only has the clock on the sensitivity list. The correct sensitivity list for the combinatorial process would include only `DataIn`, `Enable`, `currentState`, and your two variables, `counter` and `dataIndex`. Variables can't be a part of your sensitivity list because they are out of scope for the sensitivity list (also you do not want to trigger your process off of itself, more on that in a moment).

The sensitivity list is, however, mostly just a crutch for simulators. When translated to real hardware, processes are implemented in LUTs and Flip Flops. Your current implementation will never synthesize because you incorporate feedback (signals or variables that get assigned a new value as a function of their old value) in unclocked logic, producing a combinatorial loop.

`counter` and `dataIndex` are part of your state data. The state machine is simpler to understand because they are split off from the explicit state, but they are still part of the state data. When you make a two process state machine (again, I recommend 1 process state machines, not 2) you must split **all** state data into Flip Flops used to store it (such as `currentState`) and the output of the LUT that generates the next value (such as `nextState`). This means that for your two process machine, the variables `counter` and `dataIndex` must instead become `currentCounter`, `nextCounter`, `currentDataIndex`, and `nextDataIndex` and treated like your state assignment. Note that if you choose to implement changes to keep a 2-process state machine, the logic errors mentioned above the line will still apply.

---

EDIT:

Yes, resetting the `counter` back to 0 before moving into `StopBitCheck` might be a good idea, but you also need to consider that you are waiting the full 16 counts after sampling the last data bit before you even transition into `StopBitCheck`. It is only because `counter` is **not** reset that the sample is only off by one clock instead of 16. You may want to modify your `ReadData` action to transition to `StopBitCheck` as you sample the last bit when dataIndex=7 (as well as reset `counter` to 0) like so:

```
                    elsif (counter = 16) then
                        DataOut(dataIndex) <= DataIn;
                        counter <= 0;
                        if (dataIndex < 7) then
                            dataIndex <= dataIndex + 1;
                        else
                            dataIndex <= 0;
                            state <= StopBitCheck;
                        end if;
                    end if;
```

A pure state machine only stores a state. It generates its output purely from the state, or from a combination of the state and the inputs. Because `counter` and `dataIndex` are stored, they are part of the state. If you wanted to enumerate every single state you would have something like:

```
    type states is (StartBitCheck_Counter0, StartBitCheck_counter1...
```

and you would end up with 8*16*3 = 384 states (actually somewhat less because only `ReadData` uses `dataIndex`, so some of the 384 are wholly redundant states). As you can no doubt see, it is much simpler to just declare 3 separate signals since the different parts of the state data are used differently. In a two process state machine, people often forget that the signal actually named `state` isn't the only state data that needs to be stored in the clocked process.

In a 1-process machine, of course, this isn't an issue because everything that is assigned is by necessity stored in flip flops (the intermediary combinational logic isn't enumerated in signals). Also, do note that 1-process state machines and 2-process state machines will synthesize to the same thing (assuming they were both implemented correctly), although I'm of the opinion that is comparatively easier to read and more difficult to mess up a 1-process machine.

I also removed the else clauses that maintained the current state assignment in the 1-process example I provided; they are important when assigning a combinational `nextState`, but the clocked signal `state` will keep its old value whenever it isn't given a new assignment without inferring a latch.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your input! This was incredible. 

So I believe one solution to the issues before was that I did not reset my counter back to 0 before moving into StopBitCheck, I think that should clean up some of the errors that you're explaining. Is that correct?

I'm still a little lost on the last part of your explanation: "counter and dataIndex are part of your state data. The state machine simpler to understand when they are split off from the explicit state, but they are still part of the state data." Would you be able to explain this some more?

Comment: Notice all three states have a test for `enable = '1'` and no test for `'0'`, you can collapse the first if statement in each state case and change `if rising_edge(CLK) then` to `if rising_edge(CLK) and enable = '1' then`. You're better off using `DataIn = '1'` to hold counter reset in state StartBitCheck, that or impulse filter `DataIn` with two successive enabled flip flops.  The idea is to prevent a metastability event in `counter` that could skew your sample point. A UART RX can use a shift register instead of bit counter for even more simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

First Process runs just on CLK rising edge, while the second one runs on both CLK edge (because runs on every CLK change).

You use 2 process, “memory-state” and “next-state builder”, the first must be synchronous (as you done) and the second, normally, is combinatorial to be able to produce next-state in time for next CLK active edge.

But in your case the second process needs also to run on every CLK pulse (because of variable counter and index), so the solution can be to run the first on rising-edge and the second on falling-edge (if your hardware support this).

Here is your code a little bit revisited, I hope can be useful.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity ASyncReceiverV4 is
   Port ( DataIn :  in  STD_LOGIC;
          Enable :  in  STD_LOGIC;
          CLK :     in  STD_LOGIC;
          BadData : out STD_LOGIC := '0';
          DataOut : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := "00000000");
end ASyncReceiverV4;

architecture Behavioral of ASyncReceiverV4 is

   type states is (StartBitCheck, ReadData, StopBitCheck);
   signal currentState : states := StartBitCheck;
   signal nextState : states    := StartBitCheck;

begin

   process(CLK)
   begin
      if rising_edge(CLK) then
         currentState <= nextState;
      end if;
   end process;

   process(CLK)
      variable counter : integer := 0;
      variable dataIndex : integer := 0;
   begin
      if falling_edge(CLK) then
         case currentState is
            when StartBitCheck =>
               if Enable = '1' then
                  if (DataIn = '0' and counter < 8)  then
                     counter := counter + 1;
                  elsif (DataIn = '0' and counter = 8) then
                     BadData <= '0';
                     nextState <= ReadData;
                     counter := 0;
                  else
                     nextState <= StartBitCheck;
                  end if;
               end if;

            when ReadData =>
               if Enable = '1' then
                  if counter < 15 then
                     counter := counter + 1;
                  elsif (counter = 15 and dataIndex < 8) then
                     DataOut(dataIndex) <= DataIn;
                     counter := 0;
                     dataIndex := dataIndex + 1;
                  elsif dataIndex = 8 then
                     dataIndex := 0;
                     nextState <= StopBitCheck;
                  else
                     nextState <= ReadData;
                  end if;
               end if;

            when StopBitCheck =>
               if Enable = '1' then
                  if DataIn = '1' then
                     if counter < 15  then
                        counter := counter + 1;
                        nextState <= StopBitCheck;
                     elsif counter = 15 then
                        counter := 0;
                        nextState <= StartBitCheck;
                     end if;
                  else
                     DataOut <= "11111111";
                     BadData <= '1';
                     nextState <= StartBitCheck;
                  end if;
               end if;

         end case;
      end if;
   end process;

end Behavioral;
```

This is a 0x55 with wrong stop bit receive data simulation

[image]

Comment: Having the second process run on the falling clock edge is an inefficient workaround for a problem that can be easily fixed. The right approach is to either move to a 1-process state machine (my preference, also easier to read and write) or give all the clocked variables (which would be better as signals) the same current/next clocked/combinational treatment as the state.

Comment: Yes you are right. My fix (that works) was as much as possible closed to the  original code and the frequency is so slow that I can't imagine negative effect on clocking on both edge.